# Como hacer que una imagen/enlace actue de forma independiente dentro de un div/enlace

Tags: javascript, html

tengo un div que actua como un enlace y dentro de este div tengo una imagen que actua como otro enlace diferente, cuando hago clic sobre el div me lleva a Youtube, que es su enlace, pero cuando le doy a la imagen me lleva a Twitch, que es su enlace, pero tambien me abre el de Youtube, que es el enlace del div, me gustaria saber como puedo hacer para que los enlaces actúen de forma independiente, que al darle clic al div me lleve a un sitio y al darle clic a la imagen me lleve al otro sitio (no que me abra los dos), gracias por adelantado y a continuacion dejo mi código:

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <script>

        function link(loc){
        var href=loc.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href;
        console.log(this);
        console.log(href);
        loc.setAttribute("onclick","window.open('"+href+"')");
        loc.removeAttribute("onmouseover","");
    }

    </script>
    <style>
        img{
            position: absolute;
            left: 20px;
            top:20px;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: red;"
    onmouseover="link(this)">
         <a class="enlace" href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank" id="enlace"></a>
         <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/"  target="_blank"><img src="coffe.jpg" alt=""  style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" id="somebutton" ></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Comment: ¿Y si pruebas a poner la imagen dentro de ese mismo div pero en un div distinto? Quiero decir, el div que tienes no tocarlo, pero meter 2 divs, en uno la imagen y en el otro el enlace

Comment: @DarkIceDust Eso no funciona.

Comment: ¿Por qué no separas los enlaces? Me refiero a meterlos en divs diferentes, como te comenta @DarklceDust. Lo que sucede es que al estar la imagen dentro del div, cuando le das click a la imagen TAMBIÉN estás dando click al div, es por eso que te abre los dos enlaces. esto se arreglaría si pusieras los enlaces en divs separados.

Comment: @Ariees Au Andromeda Hombre, ya se que asi se soluciona, es algo obvio, estoy preguntando porque tiene que ir asi obligatoriamente y quiero saber como hacerlo funcionar estando asi.